# How to execute `aerender` command line tool via NSTask/Process?

Tags: objective-c, swift, nstask

I'm trying to build a proof of concept macOS application to render an Adobe After Effects project file by executing `aerender` command line tool via NSTask/Process but not having much success.

```swift
var task: Process = Process()

func render()

    let compPath = "/Users/Admin/Documents/test-proj.aep"

    task.launchPath = "/Applications/Adobe After Effects CC 2019/aerender"
    task.arguments = ["-project", compPath,
                      "-comp", "output"]

    do {
        try task.run()
    } catch let error {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

The above code successfully launches After Effects in the background but logs produce the following output:

```
aerender version 16.1.1x4
PROGRESS: Launching After Effects...
aerender ERROR -1701: AEGetParamPt failed at line 780
```

I've also attempted putting the commands into a separate Shell script and execute that from the application instead but that also produces the same results.

I can successfully run the same commands directly in Terminal using `bash` and `zsh` and get videos rendering perfectly. So I'm thinking this is an error with NSTask/Process rather than `aerender`.

The application has:

- Application sandbox turned off
- Full disk access permissions to read
  and write.

I'm open to all ideas and answers in Obj-C or Swift at this point!

Comment: Perhaps your shell has environment variable settings that your `Process` lacks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the ESTK (ExtendScript Tool Kit) in your mac. In my case, I fixed it when I installed it.

Refer to  [Adobe Extendscript Toolkit CC download for macOS 10.13.2](https://community.adobe.com/t5/get-started/adobe-extendscript-toolkit-cc-download-for-macos-10-13-2/td-p/9568122?page=1&code=eyj4nxuioijpbxnfbmexlwtles0xlmnlciisimfszyi6iljtmju2in0.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.wqdp65bm0tix8dn6fxcayugfwoavtfy0nxkj3vninj5irdfn8bwxglqqcbfwqfqkvtugmbon5x7jmrso1x6_aom0ahs8up7up0j-bc9vabqsb4ir1n_thi9okxsc4fghc0fl7qkkewot6cpln70xy9dbjqkidb-ykvk5btuspzisjfjys7j3z-qas-ol9jfcjhlhzgnicj7riffb3ujndeo-fp39f2agsy7fdiqp7x909uoqrcoti25-6-pbkwdhfygaiqddajx0_-swmuvfo5vb_pq4l-kkr3xzd-pb--8ic3qn6l-tbkcpvchsoeqlyh8nntyeio8vkprperhhpg&guid=f218f917-dbbf-497b-875d-f0393aaf593e&x-product=ccdesktop%2F5.0.0.354&x-product-location=search:forums:link%2F0.3.2)